# .What to do when Ubuntu 14.04 LTS curl doesn't support a CA certificate, even though it's valid

Tags: 14.04, ssl, curl, certificates

On Ubuntu 14.04, I'm trying to do this `curl https://api.the-newshub.com/api/1/topics/trending/top`. It's not working but it does work when you visit using Firefox.

I've updated the certificates: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` and `update-ca-certificates -f`. Still nothing.

How often does Ubuntu's native CA certificates get updated? How often do new certificates pop up?

What's a work around if you really need to access such a URL? But you don't control the domain? But SSL verification is mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curling this works for me, but here's 2 things you could do (taken from [`man curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)):

1. In Firefox, select *Options*, then *Advanced*, then the *Encryption* tab, *View Certificates*. This opens the Certificate Manager, where you can *Export*. Be sure to select `PEM` for the "Save as type".

   Let's say you put your certificate in `~/cert.pem`, you would then use:

   ```
   curl -E ~/cert.pem https://api.the-newshub.com/api/1/topics/trending/top
   ```
2. Many older SSL-servers have problems with SSLv3 or TLS, which newer versions of OpenSSL etc use, therefore it is sometimes useful to specify what SSL-version curl should use. Use -3, -2 or -1 to specify that exact SSL version to use (for SSLv3, SSLv2 or TLSv1 respectively):

   ```
   curl -2 https://api.the-newshub.com/api/1/topics/trending/top
   ```

   Otherwise, curl will first attempt to use v3 and then v2.

   *NOTE: your site seems to use SSLv3 according to its certificate, so this second idea is probably useless.*
3. ([source](https://serverfault.com/questions/151157/ubuntu-10-04-curl-how-do-i-fix-update-the-ca-bundle), about 10.04) I've been having the same trouble and after poking around a bit found that you can download a package of CA-certs ready for curl on ubuntu directly from the curl dev site.

   ```
   cd /etc/ssl/certs
   sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
   ```

   Now curl uses the most up-to-date bundle and you're good to go.

Comment: I need it to work for both curl CLI, and curl used inside PHP (libcurl), isn't there a default location that curl looks for certificates? If there is, can I just add a new cacert bundle where that default location is? How do we find out the default location? Is it a compile-time option?

Comment: Are you running on 14.04 LTS Ubuntu as well?

Comment: I tested with Ubuntu 15.10 and `curl 7.41.0 libcurl/7.41.0` on Windows

Comment: I added a new way (3)

Comment: The only way that worked was `cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates && sudo curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o cacert.crt && sudo update-ca-certificates && sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh`. Then finally using `/etc/ssl/ca-certificates.crt` as the ca bundle to pass in as `--cacert` option. However I noticed that upon accessing the site, as I strace it, I can find that curl normally tries to find: `/etc/ssl/certs/d6325660.0`, however on my Ubuntu, that does not exist. Do you have `/etc/ssl/certs/d6325660.0` on your Ubuntu?

Comment: It's like curl normally looks into `/etc/ssl/certs`, because it's a "hashed directory". So it tries to find "/etc/ssl/certs/d6325660.0" when meeting that URL. But I don't have that file for some reason. If your curl is the same on Ubuntu, then I'm wondering what certificate does it look for...?